# iOS: UITableView reload animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation, reloaddata

I have implemented nested `UITableViews` such that, on selecting a particular row from parent Data list, gets child nodes data from server and reloads them in same `UITableview`. I have given provision to go back to parent nodes using dictionary and everything working fine. I want Navigation Style animation when I move parent data list to child data list. Could someone please help me how to do this.

I have tried using following code `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` animations it flips the view - I am looking for similar but without flip - simple navigation style animation like I want to pretend I am pushing another UITableView.

```
[UIView transitionWithView: self.listTableView
                   duration: 0.35f
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                   animations: ^(void) {
                        [self.listTableView reloadData];
                    } completion: ^(BOOL isFinished){
                    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Logic with Code.

you need to import `QuartzCore framework  in`.h` for using below piece of Code.
           AS #import

```
// Method to replace a given subview with another using a specified transition type, direction, and duration
-(void)replaceSubview:(UIView *)oldView withSubview:(UIView *)newView transition:(NSString *)transition direction:(NSString *)direction duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
     {
  // Set up the animation
  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  // Set the type and if appropriate direction of the transition, 
  if (transition == kCATransitionFade)
       {
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
   } 
  else
     {
  [animation setType:transition];
  [animation setSubtype:direction];
 }
// Set the duration and timing function of the transtion -- duration is passed in as a parameter, use ease in/ease out as the timing function
 [animation setDuration:duration];
 [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction   functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
 [[oldView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];    
   }
```

Call Above method when TableView row gets Clicked as below.

```
     [self replaceSubview:thisTableView 
                 withSubview:thisTableView 
                  transition:kCATransitionPush
                   direction:kCATransitionFromLeft
                    duration:0.3];


 //thisTableView is instance of UItableView.
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks interesting. What is kAnimationKey?

Comment: @AppleDeveloper sorry i forgot to pass it .it is `transitionViewAnimation`.and i am gonna to place it in my answer.

Comment: Worked fantastic. Thanks. Is key has to be "transitionViewAnimation"? I googled and found everyone using same string for kAnimationKey :)

Comment: @AppleDeveloper yes `transitionViewAnimation` is the `animation key` .i am suing it too.

Comment: I meant does that have any special meaning or we can use any another string say "myanimationkey".

Comment: @AppleDeveloper ohhh... sorry dude.yes you can give it any name but the value should be `transitionViewAnimation`.see my answer i have placed the animation key itself rather passing the string .

Comment: hey buddy, sorry for the confusion....i should have actually tried...I mean to ask for value only - "transitionViewAnimation" :-)

Comment: @AppleDeveloper  sorry for my wrong explanation here is right explanation about the key--- * 'key' may be any string such that only one animation per unique key.
 * is added per layer. The special key 'transition' is automatically
 * used for transition animations. The nil pointer is also a valid key.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that you are not using newview. Can you make this code generic so that same transition happens when you specify two different views?